# Remove duplicates in sub report in crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a report that contains 3 sub reports. The sub reports are coming up with duplicate data that I need to suppress.

http://i.imgur.com/7wmZf

(sorry i couldnt post the image; newbie on the site)

The columns enclosed are the subreports where suppression is needed.

I've tried using the suppress and suppress if duplicated and had no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
CRNewbie

Comment: check your query results in sql server and remove duplication at that level.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the query of each of your subreports so that they have "SELECT DISTINCT ..." instead of just "SELECT ..."

That should remove your dupes.

Comment: That sounds good....where would I go to do that? I dont see anywhere where SQL expressions are in use....

Comment: How did you tell the subreports what data to use?